# Convert Array to string and back to array in coffee script

Tags: coffeescript

I have an array of arrays  in coffe script. How to convert it in easy way to string and then back to array? So i m expecting like this.It's easy to do it in  ruby using eval.How to achieve that in a coffe script?
Thanks  in advance.

```
"[[2,3,4],[2,3,4],[4,6,7]]" =>string
and then [[2,3,4],[2,3,4],[4,6,7]] back to an array again
```

Answer (score 8):

While you could, in theory, use eval in javascript/coffeescript as well, you probably should not. A better solution would probably be to use JSON, for instance:

`coffee -e 'console.log JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]));'`

which outputs:

`[ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5, 6 ] ]`

Comment: yeah json is the way to go for this

Comment: @alexeyb Then you should mark this as your accepted answer (click the checkmark next to it).